# how to display the chart data based on changing of dropdown value

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have a dropdown, when I change the value in the dropdown I have to change the value of a half donut chart, If there is no data available I have to display "No data Available message".

My Code

**HTML**

```
            <mat-form-field >
            <mat-label *ngIf="!room_area_displayInfo">Choose Room </mat-label>
            <mat-label *ngIf="room_area_displayInfo">No Rooms Available</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="Room" name="room_id" required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let room of room_list" [value]="room.room_id" (click) = "roomid(Room)">
                {{room.room_name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>


           <div class="chart-area" *ngIf = "!currtemp_hum_predisplayInfo">
              <canvas id="daily_temp"></canvas>
          </div>
```

**Type script file**

```
  //Rooms dropdown
   room = new FormControl();
   room_list:any = ["room1", "room-2"];
   Room

   // This method will get the room id  on selecting the room.
   roomid(room_id){
   localStorage.setItem('dash_roomid', room_id);
   this.getRoom_Temp_hum_presInfo();
  }


   Room_Temp_hum_pres:any=[]
   currtemp_hum_predisplayInfo: boolean = false;
   getRoom_Temp_hum_presInfo(){
   this.Service.getRoom_Temp_hum_pres().subscribe(response=>{
      this.Room_Temp_hum_pres = response;
      if(response == null){
        this.currtemp_hum_predisplayInfo = true;
        this.currentTemperature(this.Room_Temp_hum_pres);
     }else{
       this.currtemp_hum_predisplayInfo = false;
      }
     if(this.currtemp_hum_predisplayInfo == false){
      this.currentTemperature(this.Room_Temp_hum_pres);
     }



  //Charts starts here.
  chartColors = {
    temperature: '#ff006a',
    humidity   : '#7b00ff',
    airpressure: '#ff00fb',
    themecolor:  'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
  };

//Current Temperature Gauge Chart.
 currentTemperature(Room_Temp_hum_pres){
  var daily_temp_data = Room_Temp_hum_pres['temperature'];
  var daily_temp_data_chart = new Chart('daily_temp', {
    type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
      labels: ['Temperature'],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Temperature',
          data: [daily_temp_data, daily_temp_data+25],
          backgroundColor: [this.chartColors.temperature, this.chartColors.themecolor],
          borderColor: [this.chartColors.temperature, this.chartColors.themecolor],
          borderWidth: 1
      }]
  },
  options: {
      responsive:true,
      circumference: Math.PI,
      rotation:Math.PI,
      cutoutPercentage:60,
      title: {
          display: true,
          text: daily_temp_data+' °F' ,
          position: 'bottom',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          align: 'center',
          y: 20,
          fontSize:25,
          fontColor:'black'
      },
      legend: {
          display:false
      },
      tooltips: {
          enabled: false
    },
      animation: {
          animateScale: true,
          animateRotate: true
      }

  }
});
```

}

**Problem Facing**:

For Room Name "room-2" I have data coming from the APIs, When I change the dropdown value from "room-2" to "room1" chart is not displaying which is correct. But Again when we change from "room1" to "room-2" chart has to display but it is not displaying, If I do double click then only the chart is displaying but for the one-click chart is not displaying, when I print the response on the console the response is printing first time only.

I don't no where I have missed.

Comment: Could you provide a Stackblitz demo please?

Comment: Basic "hello world" example (change by click - but the idea is the same for dropdowns or radio buttons - get the index by simple JS code): https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/Jjdwvyr (More advanced examples under chart.js docs)